# Remove duplicate rows in CSV comparing data in only two columns with Python

Tags: python, database, parsing, csv, python-3.x

There are likely many ways to go about this, but here's the gist when it comes down to it:

I have two databases full of people, both exported into csv files. One of the databases is being decommissioned. *I need to compare each csv file (or a combined version of the two) and filter out all non-unique people in the soon-to-be decommissioned server*. This way I can import only **unique** people from the **decommissioned database** into the current database.

I only need to compare FirstName and LastName (which are two separate columns). Part of the problem is they are not *precise* duplicates, the names are all capitalized in one database, and very in the other.

Here is an example of the data when I combine the two csv files into one. The all CAPS names are from the current database (which is how the csv is currently formatted):

```
FirstName,LastName,id,id2,id3
John,Doe,123,432,645
Jacob,Smith,456,372,383
Susy,Saucy,9999,12,8r83
Contractor ,#1,8dh,28j,153s
Testing2,Contrator,7463,99999,0283
JOHN,DOE,999,888,999
SUSY,SAUCY,8373,08j,9023
```

Would be parsed into:

```
Jacob,Smith,456,372,383
Contractor,#1,8dh,28j,153s
Testing2,Contrator,7463,99999,0283
```

Parsing the other columns is irrelevant, but obviously the data is very relevant, so it must remain untouched. (There are actually dozens of other columns, not just three).

To get an idea of how many duplicates I actually had, I ran this script (taken from a previous post):

```
with open('1.csv','r') as in_file, open('2.csv','w') as out_file:
    seen = set() # set for fast O(1) amortized lookup
    for line in in_file:
        if line in seen: continue # skip duplicate

        seen.add(line)
        out_file.write(line)
```

Too simple for my needs though.

Comment: Your duplicate entries have different values for the *other* columns.  How do you decide which values to keep?

Comment: Is it tab delimited?

Comment: wwii - Yea, each server has different encryption, so even if the real value is the same, it's recorded in database differently. I will keep the values associated with the current server (capitalized names). But since I'll be appending the current database with only the unique names, this won't matter.

Comment: Padraic C - Currently, it's comma delimited. But I can change that to whatever is convenient.

Comment: Ok, then we can use the csv module, I will edit

Comment: @cDitch, I edited your question as you have stated you file is comma separated not tab or space delimited

Comment: Thanks for that, my apologies.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using a set is no good unless you actually want to keep one unique line of with recurring values not only keep lines that are unique, you need to find the unique values looking through all the file first which a `Counter` dict will do:

```
with open("test.csv", encoding="utf-8") as f, open("file_out.csv", "w") as out:
    from collections import Counter
    from csv import reader, writer
    wr = writer(out)
    header = next(f) # get header
    # get count of each first/last name pair lowering each string
    counts = Counter((a.lower(), b.lower()) for a, b, *_ in reader(f))
    f.seek(0) # reset counter 
    out.write(next(f))  # write header ?
    # iterate over the file again, only keeping rows which have
    # unique first and second names
    wr.writerows(row for row in reader(f)
                   if counts[row[0].lower(),row[1].lower()] == 1)
```

Input:

```
FirstName,LastName,id,id2,id3
John,Doe,123,432,645
Jacob,Smith,456,372,383
Susy,Saucy,9999,12,8r83
Contractor,#1,8dh,28j,153s
Testing2,Contrator,7463,99999,0283
JOHN,DOE,999,888,999
SUSY,SAUCY,8373,08j,9023
```

file_out:

```
FirstName,LastName,id,id2,id3
Jacob,Smith,456,372,383
Contractor,#1,8dh,28j,153s
Testing2,Contrator,7463,99999,0283
```

`counts` counts how many times each of the names appear after being lowered. We then reset the pointer and only write lines whose first two column values are only seen once in the whole file.

Or without the csv module which may be faster if you have namy columns:

```
with open("test.csv") as f, open("file_out.csv","w") as out:
    from collections import Counter
    header = next(f) # get header
    next(f) # skip blank line
    counts = Counter(tuple(map(str.lower,line.split(",", 2)[:2])) for line in f)
    f.seek(0) # back to start of file
    next(f), next(f) # skip again
    out.write(header) # write original header ?
    out.writelines(line for line in  f
                   if counts[map(str.lower,line.split(",", 2)[:2])] == 1)
```

Comment: comma delimited to answer your question, but I can change this if needed.

Thanks for the reply

Comment: Is there actually a blank line after the header?

Answer (score 1):

You could use the pandas package for this

```
import pandas as pd
import StringIO
```

replace the StringIO with path to your csv files

```
df1 = pd.read_table(StringIO.StringIO('''FirstName    LastName    id     id2    id3
John         Doe         123    432    645
Jacob        Smith       456    372    383
Susy         Saucy       9999   12     8r83
Contractor   #1          8dh    28j    153s
Testing2     Contrator   7463   99999  0283'''), delim_whitespace=True)

df2 = pd.read_table(StringIO.StringIO('''FirstName    LastName    id     id2    id3
JOHN         DOE         999    888    999
SUSY         SAUCY       8373   08j    9023'''), delim_whitespace=True)
```

Concatenate and uppercase the names

```
df1['name'] = (df1.FirstName + df1.LastName).str.upper()
df2['name'] = (df2.FirstName + df2.LastName).str.upper()
```

Select rows from df1 that do not match names from df2

```
df1[~df1.name.isin(df2.name)]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can keep the idea of using a set.  Just define a function that will return what you are interested in:

```
def name(line):
    line = line.split(',')
    n = ' '.join(line[:2])
    return n.lower()
```

Without concatenating the two databases, read the names in the current database into a set.

```
with open('current.csv') as f:
    next(f)
    current_db = {name(line) for line in f}
```

Check the names in the decommissioned db and write them if not *seen*.

```
with open('decommissioned.csv') as old, open('unique.csv', 'w') as out:
    next(old)
    for line in old:
        if name(line) not in current_db:
            out.write(line)
```

Answer (score -1):

You need to operate on a case-insignificant concatenation of the names.  For instance:

```
with open('1.csv','r') as in_file, open('2.csv','w') as out_file:
    seen = set() # set for fast O(1) amortized lookup
    for line in in_file:
        field_list = line.split(' ')
        key_name = (field_list[0] + "_" + filed_list[1]).lower()
        if key_name in seen: continue # skip duplicate

        seen.add(key_name)
        out_file.write(line)
```

Answer (score -1):

```
changed since it is in csv format 

    from collections import defaultdict

    dd = defaultdict(list)
    d = {}

    import re

with open("data") as f:
    for line in f:
        line = line.strip().lower()
        mobj =  re.match('(\w+),(\w+|#\d),(.*)',line)
        firstf, secondf, rest = mobj.groups()
        key = firstf + "_" + secondf
        d[key] = rest
        dd[key].append(rest)


    for k, v in d.items():
        print(k, v)
```

**output**

```
jacob_smith 456,372,383

testing2_contrator 7463,99999,0283

john_doe 999,888,999

susy_saucy 8373,08j,9023

contractor_#1 8dh,28j,153s

jacob_smith 456 372 383
```

**output**

```
for k, v in dd.items():
    print(k,v)


jacob_smith ['456,372,383']

testing2_contrator ['7463,99999,0283']

john_doe ['123,432,645', '999,888,999']

susy_saucy ['9999,12,8r83', '8373,08j,9023']

contractor_#1 ['8dh,28j,153s']
```